# Touch Command not working in bash for some reason

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell

Something as simple as this is working surely

```
#!/bin/bash
touch /sdcard/successful.txt
```

But its not working in my actual bash command

```
#!/bin/bash
PACKAGE='com.mixplorer'
if [ $(pidof $PACKAGE) ]; then
  am force-stop com.mixplorer && am start -n com.mixplorer/.activities.BrowseActivity
fi

if [ ! $(pidof $PACKAGE) ]; then
  am start -n com.mixplorer/.activities.BrowseActivity
fi

loopcleaner()
{
  rm -rf /sdcard/log.txt
}

while [ $(pidof $PACKAGE) ]
do
  loopcleaner
  sleep 2

  if [ ! $(pidof $PACKAGE) ]; then
    touch /sdcard/successful.txt
    exit 0;
  fi
done
```

Explanation:

1. As soon as script is executed , first check if file manager with package name 'com.mixplorer' is active 
   If yes , then force stop it and open it again
   If no , then just simply open it.
2. Now that the file manager is already opened , keep deleting a file named 'log.txt' as defined by loopcleaner every 10 seconds in a loop forever as long as file manager process is running.
3. The above cleaning activity should work only till file manager process is running , Once it stops create a file named successful.txt .Script should end immediately now.

So after i have exited my file manager , the successful.text doesn't gets created in my internal storage for some reason ( which works well if simply touch command is executed )

Comment: Why don't you move the `touch` out of the `while` loop?

Comment: @Philippos regarding while , yes its a loop but i assumed that it doesn't necessarily need a break because it will only last as long as the file manager is active.

Comment: Still, you can move the `touch` after the `done`. You can drop the `if` then and avoid the (theoretical) chance that file manager process exits between `if` check and `while` check.

Comment: @Philippos Removing the touch from while loop is causing successful.txt to be created too early . its getting created the first time file manager is opened , i want it to get created after file manager has been closed

Comment: Also dont' use `rm -rf` on files. only use `-r` on directories.

Comment: @BadalSingh How could it leave the `while` loop and issue the `touch` before the file manager is closed?

Comment: @Philippos If you don't mind , can you tell exactly so that i may paste the code which needs to be replaced i think i maybe doing it wrong being very new to bash ( just started yesterday )

Comment: Try adding `echo "debug"` inside the `if` statement of the `touch` command maybe it's never getting there.

Comment: @Shmuel Damm you are right.  I tried echo. Its not even reaching till there it seems ;-;

Comment: I believe your `touch` command is never executing because the application never fully terminates. I don't know what application you're running, so it's a bit difficult to test, but some GUI software may stay running in the background even after the user has closed them, to be able to start up quicker next time.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it by adding a break after my touch command.

```
while [ $(pidof $PACKAGE) ]
do
  loopcleaner
  sleep 2

  if [ ! $(pidof $PACKAGE) ]; then
    touch /sdcard/successful.txt
    break
    exit 0;
  fi
done
```

( although i am very much new to bash and not really confident of myself if this this is the best approach so any further edit/ suggestions to improve it will be lot appreciated )

Comment: This makes no sense. Why would the `break` change the way the code behaves if the next statement is `exit`?

Comment: [In comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/545287/touch-command-not-working-in-bash-for-some-reason/625388#comment1011462_545287), you mention that the code does not even go into the `if` statement.